# iPhone to iPad Scale-up

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, scale

I am working with an iOS developer on Elance on a reading log app for the iPhone. I designed my wireframes in Keynote using a 320x480 px background as my 'canvas'. The app is scheduled for completion in early November. However, I would like to release a version of this app for the iPad- my 5th graders all have iPads and I would like them to take advantage of this free app. My developer has offered to code an iPad version of my app (You-Log Reading) and has told me I can save money if I can provide him with the scaled-up wireframes. My problem is mostly that my math skills don't stretch much beyond 6th grade! Are there any easy ways that I can convert my wireframes from 3:2 to 4:3 ratio? So, for example, if I have a text box that is 215x84 px on my 320x480 canvas, I can use a formula to scale up this text box to 1024x768?

Update:

I did find an answer to my question outside of stackoverflow and thought I'd share it here in case others had the same question:

the difference in dimensions from 320x480 to 384x512 (outer frames) are:
384/320 by 512/480 = 1.2x1.067

So now you take the smaller box inside the original and you multiply the x and the y by the dimension ratios. So:
215 x 84
215 * 1.2 = 258
84 * 1.067 = 89.628

So 258x90 is probably going to be your new dimension of the smaller image inside the larger image.

Think of it as just the rate of change for the x axis and the rate of change for the y axis. In this case, you're changing the x axis by 1.2 times, going from 320 to 384. And you're changing the y axis by 1.067 times, going from 480 to 512.
Then you apply the rate of change for the x and y axis of the smaller image contained within the larger image.

Comment: Do yo want this to achieve in your actual project or do you want this for your wireframes ?

Comment: Both. My developer informer me that he hard-coded the images rather than use xib files and so we'd need the individual dimensions for the scale up.